# How to locate the Power Pads on a MacBook Pro A1398

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

My mac will no longer power up via the keyboard. I have taken the back off and have it before me with the fans at the bottom and the batteries at the top.
How can I jump-start the Mac ?

I have tried to find the Power Pads but to no avail.

I have also read about shorting pins #5 and #29 of the keyboard cable but unsure where this is and which pins exactly to short.

My question is how to start the Mac using either method above or another.

Comment: Take it to an Apple store or an authorized server center.

Comment: I would like to fix it myself, I just need to know where the power pads are on this model.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this shortly after posting the question. Shorting PIN 5 of the keyboard connector (5th from right with the batteries at the top) with GROUND works. However I could only get it to work with the screen opened.

Comment: Okay, so you managed to start the Mac by disassembling it and shorting it however this doesn't really fix the problem with not being able to start the Mac normally from the keyboard. (Which is why I suggested  
taking it to an Apple store or an authorized server center.)

Comment: No but the question was simply to know where the power pads are I never asked to 'fix the problem' : )

Comment: I know what your question addressed however did you not say to me in your first comment "_I would like to fix it myself_"!  To me that implies _fixing_ the underlying problem that precipitated the question asked as you're not really _fixing_ anything by jump starting it.  Regardless though having to continually as needed jump start the device without _fixing_ the underlying issue is, IMO, really not an acceptable long term solution even though it answered your original specific question.

Comment: I never said it was a long term solution. Its just the first step in confirming that the main board is ok. As per my comment to Allen below, all is working 'except' the power button, so my next task it work out why and decide whether I need to replace the entire keyboard or just that key...

Comment: I didn't see your comment to Allan before I wrote my previous comment, sorry.  Have you tried cleaning it yet?  Also the "A1398" Model No is applicable to MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012), (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013), (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) and (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) so we don't actually know which one you have and without cannot definitively say without checking on all of them whether you'll have to replace the keyboard if cleaning doesn't fix it.  Although if cleaning it doesn't you'll probably have to replace the entire keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, its a mid 2014 model. The power button is now working fine to boot up which is great, no need hotwire the ribbon cable anymore. The only problem now is that the mac is shutting down as if the power button is being pressed. I assume it's sticking and I will need to dismantle the keyboard to clean it.

Comment: BTW Hope cleaning it works for you otherwise, unless you have a source for the Keyboard only, you'll probably have to replace the Upper Case Assembly which includes the Upper Case with Keyboard, Trackpad, and Battery.

Comment: Audrey, i am having this exact problem and this is the only resource i can find that applies to my model. May i ask where you located the keyboard connector pins? I am at a loss!

Comment: @user3439894 I have a macbook with water damage here on my desk. It does not turn on and before taking it to anyone, I wanted to check if it's only the keyboard that is broken. By shortening the contacts, I found out that the mainboard is still functional, but the keyboard, touchpad and screen are not. All that in 5 minutes work.